# Dreams and symbolism. Are dreams trully indicative of what is about to happen or do they merely serve as symbolic direction of what path to follow?

Tags: dreams

What does it mean for a man to keep dreaming of being pregnant??? Is it normal or does it have a special symbolism? Pls help if you have expertise in interpreting such things